# Binding to IP address and port number

Tags: python, scapy

I have 2 hosts, 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2. Both send different custom protocols over UDP port 1234. So 192.168.1.1 sends my_proto1 over port 1234 and 192.168.1.2 sends my_proto2 over port 1234.
I'm now trying to use `bind_layers` to bind the correct host to the correct custom protocol and running into problems because the IP address is at the IP layer and the port number is at the UDP layer. I tried using 2 bind_layers like so:

```
bind_layers(IP, my_proto1, src="192.168.1.1")
bind_layers(UDP, my_proto1, sport=1234)
```

This works for mapping a single host to a single protocol, but doesn't work when I add the 2nd protocol

```
bind_layers(IP, my_proto1, src="192.168.1.1")
bind_layers(UDP, my_proto1, sport=1234)

bind_layers(IP, my_proto2, src="192.168.1.2")
bind_layers(UDP, my_proto2, sport=1234)
```

Anyone have any suggestion for how to either use a single bind_layers to bind by both IP address and port number or how to use a combination of bind_layers that works?
Thanks

Comment: How does this even work. src=192.168... is gonna throw a syntax error

Comment: There should be quotes around the IP address. I've updated the question.

Comment: Don't you need `dport` instead of `sport` by any chance? Scapy Noob asking.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues yes typically you would want the dport since the sport will change but in my case the sport is static. Regardless of which is used, the problem still remains.